# React to all Function App Slot Swaps across Subscription/Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I want to react to my Function App Events, specifically when a slot is swapped. I have hundreds of Function Apps which I want to Monitor but I want all the events to be handled by a single Event Handler (probably a Logic App).

I have multiple Logic Apps and Function Apps stored in a Subscription. I want to be able to use Event Grid to monitor them and react to changes. For the Logic Apps, I wanted to know every time a Logic App is saved which was fairly easy to do - I created an Event Grid which looks at Resources across a subscription and is triggered when any Resources are written successfully. And then I added some filtering so that it only reacts to Logic Apps (Microsoft.Logic/workflows) which works very well.

Where I am struggling is with the Function Apps. I want to monitor all the Function Apps and look out for any slots being swapped. I can do this by creating an event grid for each Function App but this seems wasteful to do for every singe one, whereas for the Logic App I can just have a single Event Grid which monitors everything.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Event Grid to monitor the events from multiple Function Apps and have a single Event handler as a Logic App to process the events.

- Created event grid as shown in below image by taking Endpoint type as Azure function and Endpoint as EventGridTrigger1.
  [image]
- After that In Event Grid Enable Subject Filtering in Filters and then take **Microsoft. Web/sites/*/slots/swapped** in Subject begins with field to allow the Event Grid to subscribe to all slot swapped events across all your Function Apps in the subscription.
  [image]
- In function app we are taking Azure Event Grid Trigger as function.
  [image]
- Then Create a logic App in the same subscription ,resource group and same region as function App and EventGrid taken  .
- When a resource event occurs Event grid trigger and Filter array action taken.
  [image]
- In the When a resource event occurs trigger configuration, select the Resource Type as Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics and Resource Name as  you created EventGridName.
- Then add an "Filter array" action to filter the events to only include events from Function Apps.
  [image]
  AFAIK currently the wildcard for all azure function apps is not supported so you can create as mentioned in above process or else raise a Microsoft support for this.